# BatchDelete is not deleting all value in list

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

Trying to delete multiple row of DynamoDB.

Querying only on one table of DynamoDB.On basis the of Partition key, its returning 2 values as output, which is save in list.

[image]  Now after deleting this value using BatchDelete only first element get deleted. Sometimes on random basis second value also get deleted but that was not happened every time.

```
     DynamoDBQueryExpression<Abc> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Abc>()
                    .withHashKeyValues(abc);  
         
        List<Abc> xyz = dynamoDBMapper.query(Abc.class,queryExpression);
//xyz has size 2

        dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(xyz);
```

Should I use sleep or is there any other way.

Comment: This seems unlikely. Have you double and triple-checked you are not mistaking what's happening here?

Comment: Yes I have checked. 8/10 is working fine, for rest of them I have debug the code also, Value is passing through batchDelete but value is still in DynamoDB

Comment: Capture and print out the result of the batchDelete call. It will be a list of DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch objects, indicating which keys were not deleted, and why. After that, if you're sure this is a bug in DynamoDB (or the mapper SDK) then you might consider raising a support ticket with AWS and provide a failing request ID. This would be a serious bug in DynamoDB affecting lots of people (which is what makes me think it's unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Java V1 here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples

You will see it's marked as **deprecated**.

[image]

I strongly recommend that you upgrade to the AWS SDK for Java v2 API.

When working with Java V2 and DynamoDB, the Enhanced Client offers a straightforward way to map client-side classes to DynamoDB tables. This is documented in the **Java V2 Developer Guide** here:

[Mapping items in DynamoDB tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html)

To use the Enhanced Client to delete multiple items, you can use this Java code:

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.DeleteItemEnhancedRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.WriteBatch;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.import]

/*
 * Before running this code example, create an Amazon DynamoDB table named Customer with these columns:
 *   - id - the id of the record that is the key
 *   - custName - the customer name
 *   - email - the email value
 *   - registrationDate - an instant value when the item was added to the table
 *
 * Also, ensure that you have set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class EnhancedBatchDeleteItems {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
            .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
            .build();
        deleteBatchRecords(enhancedClient);
        ddb.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.main]
    public static void deleteBatchRecords(DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient) {
        try {
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> mappedTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));
            Key key1 = Key.builder()
                .partitionValue("id110")
                .build();

            Key key2 = Key.builder()
                .partitionValue("id120")
                .build();

            BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest request = BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                .writeBatches(WriteBatch.builder(Customer.class)
                    .mappedTableResource(mappedTable)
                    .addDeleteItem(DeleteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                        .key(key1)
                        .build())
                    .build(),
                WriteBatch.builder(Customer.class)
                    .mappedTableResource(mappedTable)
                    .addDeleteItem(DeleteItemEnhancedRequest.builder()
                        .key(key2)
                        .build())
                    .build())
                .build();

            // Delete these two items from the table.
            enhancedClient.batchWriteItem(request);
            System.out.println("Records deleted");

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.batchdelete.main]
}
```

You can find this example and other Java v2 DynamoDB examples in [AWS Code Example Github](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb).

Comment: *When working with Java V2 and DynamoDB, its recommended that you use the Enhanced Client*, can you provide documentation that Enhanced Client is recommended when using Java V2?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue with your code, I have tested similar and works for me with no issue. My first suggestion would be to ensure you wrap your code in a `try/catch` block:

```
        try {

            DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

            Reply key = new Reply();
            key.setPk("1");

            DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Reply>()
                    .withHashKeyValues(key)
                    .withReturnConsumedCapacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL)
                    .withScanIndexForward(false);

            List<Reply> latestReplies = mapper.query(Reply.class, queryExpression);
            
            // Log keys here to be sure you are deleting the correct item
            for (Reply c: latestReplies) {
                System.out.println(c.getPk());
            }

            mapper.batchDelete(latestReplies);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Error running: " + t);
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I would suggest that you implement some logging, just to be sure that the items you read are the ones you expected to be deleted.

It may also be worth enabling [CloudTrail Dataplane Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html#ddb-data-plane-events-in-cloudtrail) which will allow you to see all the dataplane events being executed on the table.

You may also enable [HTTP wire logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html) to provide you another level of logging, however, this is not advised for production workloads as the logging is quite verbose.